# Cpanel Installation error in centos7

Tags: web-services, cpanel, centos7

I am using centos7 and i just want to install cpanel in my server. But when i am installing this it shows some error.

```
[root@cpanel home]# sh latest 
Verifying archive integrity... All good.
Uncompressing Cpanel & WHM Installer.....
        ____                  _
    ___|  _ \ __ _ _ __   ___| |
   / __| |_) / _` | '_ \ / _ \ |
  | (__|  __/ (_| | | | |  __/ |
   \___|_|   \__,_|_| |_|\___|_|

  Installer Version v00049 r4acea837e68e6bac6c7d8d61a9d5d6cb8a0640c6

Beginning main installation.
2015-12-11 20:02:56  581 ( INFO): cPanel & WHM installation started at: Fri Dec 11 20:02:56 2015!
2015-12-11 20:02:56  582 ( INFO): This installation will require 20-50 minutes, depending on your hardware.
2015-12-11 20:02:56  583 ( INFO): Now is the time to go get another cup of coffee/jolt.
2015-12-11 20:02:56  584 ( INFO): The install will log to the /var/log/cpanel-install.log file.
2015-12-11 20:02:56  585 ( INFO): 
2015-12-11 20:02:56  586 ( INFO): Beginning Installation v3...
2015-12-11 20:02:56  391 ( INFO): CentOS 7 (Linux) detected!
2015-12-11 20:02:56  407 ( INFO): Checking RAM now...
2015-12-11 20:02:56  466 ( INFO): Validating that the system hostname ('networkworldit.com') is a FQDN...
2015-12-11 20:02:56 1259 (DEBUG):   - ssystem [BEGIN]: /scripts/rdate
open3: exec of /scripts/rdate failed at /home/cPanelInstall/selfgz8423/install line 238.
Removing /root/installer.lock.
```

Comment: You should ask your question on server-fault: http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can try move /usr/local/cpanel out of the way and restart cPanel installation process on your server.